How are these electronics PCB design constants calculated or decided on?
I've asked this in the Electronics Stack exchange with no real answers so maybe a mathematician could help! PCB trace width calculators like this one and many others like it always quote at the bottom some constants they use for their calculations, like so,

For IPC-2221 internal layers: k = 0.024, b = 0.44, c = 0.725
For IPC-2221 external layers: k = 0.048, b = 0.44, c = 0.725
where k, b, and c are constants resulting from curve fitting to the
IPC-2221 curves

looking at the IPC-2221 document here (page 50 on the PDF, 38 of the document) are the curves that they mention, but I can't find online or in the paper how they figured out those values for k, b, and c. Can someone assist me in understanding how these values were "curve fitted"? Are they even correct? Is curve fitting acceptable in this case?

The previous question

I don't think it helps at all but thanks for linking it.
